# How to get HDMI Port info from EDID block?

Tags: display, hdmi, edid

I am trying to get the HDMI port from the EDID data. So far I have taken the EDID data by connecting to different HDMI ports (say 1,2,3,4).When I compared the data, I can find the 0xAA byte of EDID data is varying for each port with the values 0x10,0x20,0x30,0x40 respectively. When I searched for the CEA-861-E details of EDID, the address oxAA is reserved field. Below is the link for CEA-861 specification I referred.
[http://electronix.ru/forum/index.php?act=Attach&type=post&id=77872][1]

So my question is, how to know the port ID for the HDMI from EDID data? Is my understanding based on my experiment correct?

Your suggestions are highly appropriated.

Cheers,
Gopinath

Comment: Can you please provide few samples of EDIDs?

Comment: Hi ramzes2, Thanks for the reply. I have figured out how to detect port ID from EDID data.  It can be found in the vendor specific data block. A "Vendor Specific Data Block" (if any) contains as its first three bytes the vendor's IEEE 
24-bit registration number, LSB first. For HDMI, it is always 00-0C-03 for HDMI Licensing, LLC.
It is followed by a two byte source physical address, LSB first. The source physical address provides the CEC physical address for upstream CEC devices.

Answer (score 0):

It can be found in the vendor specific data block. A "Vendor Specific Data Block" (if any) contains as its first three bytes the vendor's IEEE 
24-bit registration number, LSB first. For HDMI, it is always 00-0C-03 for HDMI Licensing, LLC.
It is followed by a two byte source physical address, LSB first. The source physical address provides the CEC physical address for upstream CEC devices.
For more details, please refer the below post. http://www.bitsandqubits.com/2017/06/detecting-hdmi-port-id-from-edid-data.html

Comment: None of these links work. Do you have an updated one that I can reference today? I'm looking to add a Vendor Specific Data Block to fake a display into being a VR headset.